# C++ lvalues, rvalues, references, parameters, and performance

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, lvalue, rvalue

So I have a function that needs to take an std::vector as a parameter. I'd like to know the best way to declare the parameter so that the underlying array is not deep-copied, as it could be rather large.

```
// which should I choose?
void myFunc(std::vector<char>); // 1
void myFunc(std::vector<char>&); // 2
void myFunc(std::vector<char>&&);  // 3
void myFunc(std::vector<char>*) // 4
```

Which should I choose? Also, I won't be modifying the vector in the function so shouldn't I add const? Should I overload the function and have a combination of these?

Comment: If you don't need to modify it, then `const std::vector<char>&`.

Comment: Will this work for rvalues?

Comment: in addition, probably you forgot about _cv-qualifiers_...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you are going to make a copy of it inside the function anyway:

   ```
   void myFunc(std::vector<char>);
   ```
2. If you just want to read the argument without copying it:

   ```
   void myFunc(const std::vector<char>&);
   ```
3. If you want to modify the original vector passed to the function:

   ```
   void myFunc(std::vector<char>&);
   ```
4. If you want to optimize for rvalues *or* if you want to [*move*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/3425536) the argument into the function:

   ```
   void myFunc(std::vector<char>&&);
   ```
5. If you need to be able to signify an optional argument passed by reference:

   ```
   void myFunc(const std::vector<char>*);
   ```
6. If you need to pass an optional argument that you want to modify if non-`nullptr`:

   ```
   void myFunc(std::vector<char>*);
   ```

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368690/rvalue-function-overloading option 1 will be optimized for rvalues...so I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @dwoodwardgb Yes. That's exactly why it should be used. You get a function that handles both lvalues and rvalues efficiently.

Comment: Ok, but how does option 1 work for lvalues? Won't it call the copy constructor for an std::vector?

Comment: Yes, and that's why you only use it if you were going to copy the vector inside the function anyway.

Comment: How would copying the array inside the function change anything? That is, if I'm going to copy the vector inside the function why would I also want to copy it in the function call?

Comment: If you passed the vector by ref and copied it inside the function, that wouldn't be efficient for rvalues. They'd be constructed in place of the argument and copied inside the function. By passing the vector by value you eliminate that superfluous copying step for rvalues, since the vector can be directly constructed in place of the argument, without needing to copy it after that.

Comment: Ok, so option 1 works for rvalues, whereas options 2 and 3 might not.

Comment: 1 implies that you omit the copying inside the function at let the function call handle it, so that you copy only once in the end.

Comment: 3 won't compile for rvalues, whereas 2 will and is perfectly fine you only want to read from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90742/discussion-between-dwoodwardgb-and-zenith).

Answer (score 2):

If you **don't** want to *deep copy* `std::vector`:

- *move* it into your function:

  ```
  // foo() decalaration
  void foo(std::vector<int> v);

  // usage example
  std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3};
  foo(std::move(v));
  // v is moved into foo() and invalid now
  ```

  You may also return this vector from function in the same manner:

  ```
  // foo() decalaration
  std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<int> v) {
      return v.push_back(4), std::move(v);
  }

  // usage example
  std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3};
  v = foo(std::move(v));
  // now v is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} and no one were deep copied
  ```

  But note if you don't *move* it (call `foo(v)` instead of `foo(std::move(v))`) then it will be *deep copied*. Under the hood, parameter `v` of `foo()` is just constructed by *move-constructor*.
- pass it as reference:

  ```
  // foo() declaration
  void foo(std::vector<int>& v);
  ```

  But now we have a problem: which reference and *cv-qualifiers*? Well, in general we have 2 types of references and 4 types of *cv-qualifiers*, altogether 8 declarations:

  ```
  void foo(std::vector<int>&);
  void foo(std::vector<int> const&);
  void foo(std::vector<int> volatile&);
  void foo(std::vector<int> const volatile&);
  void foo(std::vector<int>&&);
  void foo(std::vector<int> const&&);
  void foo(std::vector<int> volatile&&);
  void foo(std::vector<int> const volatile&&);
  ```

  Of course, part of them are useless and should be deleted. But nevertheless too much declarations also known as *perfect forwarding problem* (actually, there were no rvalue-references when it was a problem so the problem was 2 times smaller).

  For example, if you want to modify `v` you need 2 functions at least:

  ```
  void foo(std::vector<int>&);
  void foo(std::vector<int>&&);
  ```

  In this case you will be able to call `foo()` on lvalue objects:

  ```
  std::vector<int> v;
  foo(v);
  ```

  as well as on temporary:

  ```
  foo(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
  ```

  But how to *code* just one implementation for different reference types and / or cv-qualifiers? Let me introduce *universal references*:

  ```
  template<typename Vector>
  void foo(Vector&& v);
  ```

  `Vector&&` is **always a reference type** and may be deduced into

  - `std::vector<int>&` if you pass lvalue of type `std::vector<int>` into `foo()`:

    ```
    std::vector<int> v; 
    foo(v); // v is lvalue
    ```
  - `std::vector<int> const&` if you pass const lvalue of type `std::vector<int>`:

    ```
    std::vector<int> const v; 
    foo(v); // v is const lvalue
    ```
  - `std::vector<int>&&` if you pass rvalue:

    ```
    foo(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 2}); // v is rvalue
    ```
  - etc...

  But in this case you have to check acceptance of type `Vector`. But that is another story.

And I definitely find no sense to pass pointers instead of references in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I didn't know about the whole universal references thing. I ended up simply going with myFunc(const std::vector<char> &) because I didn't need to modify the vector at all.

Comment: @dwoodwardgb yea, it depends on purposes. In addition, `auto&&` is universal reference too.